# Android Creating a playable story

Tags: android

I am trying to create a playable story that progresses via choices made by the player.

At each stage there would be 2 or 3 choices.

E.g.

```
Text.setText("you reach some stairs");

button1.setText("go up");
button2.setText("go down");
button3.setText("jump off a cliff");
```

However the only way I can think of making this work is by having a huge line of if else statements inside each other, or having about 40 different Activitys.

Is there a simpler way of doing this?

Comment: Use a switch statement !

Comment: not clear about your questions. Mind elaborate  more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up settling for Switch statements as suggested by RBK

its still not ideal but it is a much better alternative

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, I would do something like this:

```
private void stairs() {
    text.setText("you reach some stairs");
    button1.setText("go up");
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            attic();
        }
    });
    button2.setText("go down");
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            basement();
        }
    });
    button3.setText("jump off a cliff");
    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            endOfGame();
        }
    });
}

private void attic() {
    ...
}

...
```

Please notice, that this is an untested code, I just typed it out here.